# Android Fragment setRetainInstance(true) is not working on backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I want to keep a Fragment alive even if it is not shown anymore. Because I have some AsyncTasks going there.

Firstly I am adding a starting point `Fragment`

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();   
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentMenu, menuFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Later on I replace `menuFragment` with the Fragment which should stay alive

```
 FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 ft.replace(R.id.fragmentMenu, btFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Lastly I override the `onBackPressed()` method for using `popBackStack()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0){
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Inside my `btFragment` which should stay alive even if I pop another Fragment I have set  `setRetainInstance(true)` inside the `onCreate()` method.
But it is getting destroyed as soon as I pop the backstack.

Am I doing something wrong? thx

Comment: Its best to run async task and loader tasks in the activity and not in the fragment. Best not to depend on fragment to hold any data. Keep it in the activity and let the fragment get it from the activity when the fragment resumes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a little bit of a workaround. Here is the code if anyone is interested in it.

```
// little work-around to not let btFragment die.
        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentMenu);
        if (fragment instanceof BTFragment) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragment).add(R.id.fragmentMenu, menuFragment).commit();

        } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

Basically I'm hiding the Fragment instead of removing it and by checking the `FrameLayout` for the current Fragment I can handle different Fragments. With this way, the `onDestroy()` method is not called on my btFragment.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [setRetainInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) explains that it applies only to activity recreation:

> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity
>   re-creation (such as from a configuration change)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I found a way to keep a Fragment alive.